# Formula checks A1 and return value, if blank, return value in A2, if A2 is blank, return value in A3, if A3 is blank then display a message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if, ignore, blank

I guess I just needed to have a closer look at each of my formulas' opening and closing statements and I figured it out.

Below is my original post for posterity:
 
Not sure if anyone can help me with this. I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that is super simple, for someone who doesn't know excel at all, to use.

> [image]

Sheet 1 is the "Display" (printable) sheet which will show the final results.
Sheet 2 is the "Data Input" sheet and titled as such.
Sheet 3 is where I'll keep all my necessary lists and is titled "Lists."
Sheet 4 ("MAIN REPORT" sheet) is for anyone who wants to go the extra mile and paste data from a different excel report. This data will be used to show data in a cell...explained below:

In the Display sheet, I have two columns, Column A and B, titled "Trip #" and "Distance" respectively. In A2 I have a drop down list to select a Trip # from 1-10. In B2 I need a formula which checks the sheet titled "Data Input" for a value from three different cells: A2, A3, A4 in priority order.

Example: Check A2 for any value and return that value. If A2 is blank, then check A3 for any value and return that value. If A3 is blank, then check A4 for any value and return that value. Finally if A4 is blank, return a message that reads "Enter Distance". It should be noted that the formula should ignore other formulas in the target cells (A2, A3, and A4) and only focus on the final value of any formula.

I do have a bit of a wild card, in the Data Input sheet, for A2 I have it setup so the user can select an option from a drop-down list (km from 1-30). If they choose not to use the drop-down list then they can type the answer manually in A3. If they don't use either of previous input methods, A4 has a formula which can return data if the user copies the data from another report in into the MAIN REPORT sheet.

TL;DR: Formula to check cell 1, return any value found, if cell 1 is blank, check cell 2 and return any value found, if cell 2 is blank, check cell 3 and return any value found, if cell 3 is also empty, then display a message. Ignore formulas in each cell.

Comment: This site is not a free scripting site. If you have tried something and it did not work, share your code/scripts so we can help you debug it. But as it stands, this question will most likely be closed for lack of showing effort.

Comment: SO VERY SORRY about that. I forgot to include the formula I was working with. I ended up finding the solution by careful studying my formula for errors. I have updated it to show the formula that worked in the end.



Solution: =IF(ISBLANK(A2),IF(ISBLANK(A3),IF(ISBLANK(A4),"ENTER DISTANCE",A4),A3),A2)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),IF(ISBLANK(A3),IF(ISBLANK(A4),"ENTER DISTANCE",A4),A3),A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter syntax in Office 365 would be:
`=IFERROR(@TOCOL(A1:A4,1),"Enter distance")`

Or if it's not true blanks (formula's resulting in blank):

`=@FILTER(A1:A4,LEN(A1:A4),"Enter distance")`

Comment: Thank you!! I’ll give this a try as well.